# What is the best way to deal with approval and reviewing of a document content using sharepoint?

Tags: approval-process

We need to send out an email that has to be approved and reviewed (by making changes and suggestions) by a group of people.
What is the best way to do this using Sharepoint? This is for Sharepoint in Microsoft 365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest building an approval workflow using Power Automate. I have a YouTube video that covers the process in detail: [Building Approval Workflows with Power Automate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMQgwjkcrTQ)

**Update to address comment:**

In your comment you mentioned that you are doing an approval for documents rather than list items. Most of what is shown in the video applies, you should just use the **When a file is created (properties only)** trigger, rather than the **When an item is created** trigger.

[image: Screen capture of trigger]

When you do this the Dynamic content for the trigger will include information about the document (e.g. the file name).

Comment: Hi Rob, I have not watched the entire video I just started. The video shows how to do that for a list. How do I apply that for a document (I also need to track the changes). My plan is to create a word doc, have the reviewing enables and then when it is approved I would send an email with the content of the doc. Does your video apply to this ?

Comment: @MiniMe I've updated my answer to address your comment.